# Can i use ID3 to get details of mp3 file link

Tags: id3

The mp3 file is not stored in my server.

I just have the **link** of the mp3 file.

Can i get the details using **id3** ??

Thanks.

Comment: With link you mean URL ? or soft link inside your os ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the URL with *link* then the answer is no, you cannot get more information of the linked mp3 file.

Comment: Not from its URL, but from the downloaded file directly.

Answer (score 0):

ID3 tag is a bunch of bytes at the start of file. If you can open connection to this URL and get those bytes, you can use a id3 reader lib to get this information.